# Text is not highlighted in UI through selenium execution

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

In my application, when user enters keywords in search box, matching text get highlighted.

But when same steps are executed through **selenium**,text is not highlighted.

I am using `sendKeys()` to enter text.

Comment: Add the relevant code and html

Comment: html for the search box : <span id="headerSearchTD" class="nowrap font-normal bold control" style="padding-right:3px;">Search&nbsp;
<input onblur="return HE(event,this)" onchange="return HE(event,this)" id="searchTextInput" class="padding-none font-sm PKTextSearch" style="width:75px;" pkwidgetid="PKTextSearch_searchTextInput">
<img src="/images/icon_search.gif?ver=MOBILIZER_8_4_0_20180618_1809-DEV" id="searchImg" pkevent="MouseOver,MouseOut" class="img-normal" style="vertical-align:bottom;">
</span>

Comment: WebElement txtObj = findTextBox(driver, textPath, textMethod);
            if (txtObj == null) {
                UtilFunctions.log("Text box '" + fieldName + "' object is null. Returning false.");
                return false;
            } else {
               
                txtObj.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
                txtObj.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_UP);
                txtObj.click();
                txtObj.clear();
                txtObj.sendKeys(value);
                Thread.sleep(1000);